# Java IllegalMonitorStateException

Tags: java, multithreading

I need some help to understand where my program is going wrong, I have a very simple program to learn about multithreading but every time I run the following code it gives me an IllegalStateMonitorException. I don't know what's causing this although I suspect it may be my synchronized block, Thanks.

Main Method class:

```
public class Lab8 {
    public static void main(String [] args) { 
        Thread1 thread1 = new Thread1(); 
        thread1.start();
    }
}
```

Thread 1:

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class Thread1 extends Thread {
public DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");

public Thread1() { 
    super("Thread1");
}
public void run() { 
    Thread2 thread2 = new Thread2(); 
    System.out.println("==Start: " + dateFormat.format(new Date()) + "==\n"); 
    synchronized(thread2) { 
        try {
            this.wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.err.println(e.toString()); 
        } 
        (new Thread(thread2)).start(); 
    }
    System.out.println("==End: " + dateFormat.format(new Date()) + "==\n"); 
}
}
```

Thread 2:

```
public class Thread2 implements Runnable {
@Override
public void run() {
    synchronized(this) { 
        for(int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) { 
            System.out.print(i + " ");
            if(i % 10 == 0) { 
                System.out.print("\n");
            }
        }
        notify(); 
    }
} 

}
```

Comment: If you get an exception, it is helpful to include the stack trace into your question.

Comment: Not just to include it here, but read it yourself.  If you had read the stack trace, then you would not have had to "suspect it may be [in] my synchronized block:"  You would have _known_ exactly what line of code threw the exception.

Answer (score 2):

You should understand, that the `synchronized` construct and the `wait`/`notify` mechanism are tied to an object instance. In your code, you are using

```
synchronized(thread2) { 
   …
        this.wait();
```

so the object of your `synchronized` statement and the one, you are calling `wait` on, are different. That causes the `IllegalStateMonitorException`. Note that waiting on the `Thread1` instance while the other thread is calling `notify()` on its own `Thread2` instance will not work as `notify` will wake up only threads waiting *on the same instance*.

Besides that, you should never synchronize on thread instances anyway. The reason is that the `Thread` implementation will synchronize on its own instance as well, so this might interfere. Further, you should not subclass `Thread` like you did with your `Thread1` class but rather use composition like you did with your `Thread2` class.

Comment: Yeah, except, extending `Thread` is not actually _wrong_, it's just bad design.

Comment: @james large: Well, I said “should not” in the end notes, not meant to be a dogmatic rule, however, here it is the pattern that leads to accidentally synchronizing or waiting on a thread instance by just using `this`…